# How to read sizes of packed files inside zip archive using R

Tags: r, unzip

The following code in R returns a data frame which includes filenames, unpacked length in bytes and the date (without extracting the files).

```
unzip(path_to_zip, list  = T)
```

I am wondering how I can also extract the size of the packed (compressed) files or alternatively the compression ratio for each file.

I am using Windows 7 machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `unzip()` *function*, you cannot: by default, it uses an internal C function that does what it does and nothing more. However, it can use the external executable, and that *does* allow the verbose information (with `-v`). In order to use this, you'll need to modify R's `unzip()` function. The rest of this answer is an exercise of *"use the **source**, luke"*, showing that the current functions can be extended when needed.

```
unzip2 <- function (zipfile, files = NULL, list = FALSE, list.verbose = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE, 
                    junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = ".", unzip = "internal", setTimes = FALSE) {
    if (identical(unzip, "internal")) {
        if (!list && !missing(exdir)) 
            dir.create(exdir, showWarnings = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
        res <- .External(utils:::C_unzip, zipfile, files, exdir, list, 
            overwrite, junkpaths, setTimes)
        if (list) {
            dates <- as.POSIXct(res[[3]], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
            data.frame(Name = res[[1]], Length = res[[2]], Date = dates, 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        }
        else invisible(attr(res, "extracted"))
    }
    else {
        WINDOWS <- .Platform$OS.type == "windows"
        if (!is.character(unzip) || length(unzip) != 1L || !nzchar(unzip)) 
            stop("'unzip' must be a single character string")
        zipfile <- path.expand(zipfile)
        if (list) {
            dashl <- if (list.verbose) "-lv" else "-l"
            res <- if (WINDOWS) 
                system2(unzip, c(dashl, shQuote(zipfile)), stdout = TRUE)
            else system2(unzip, c(dashl, shQuote(zipfile)), stdout = TRUE, 
                env = c("TZ=UTC"))
            l <- length(res)
            res2 <- res[-c(1, 3, l - 1, l)]
            con <- textConnection(res2)
            on.exit(close(con))
            z <- read.table(con, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
            dt <- paste(z$Date, z$Time)
            formats <- if (max(nchar(z$Date) > 8)) 
                c("%Y-%m-%d", "%d-%m-%Y", "%m-%d-%Y")
            else c("%m-%d-%y", "%d-%m-%y", "%y-%m-%d")
            slash <- any(grepl("/", z$Date))
            if (slash) 
                formats <- gsub("-", "/", formats)
            formats <- paste(formats, "%H:%M")
            for (f in formats) {
                zz <- as.POSIXct(dt, tz = "UTC", format = f)
                if (all(!is.na(zz))) 
                  break
            }
            z[, "Date"] <- zz
            z <- z[, colnames(z) != "Time"]
            nms <- c("Name", "Length", "Date")
            z[, c(nms, setdiff(colnames(z), nms))]
        }
        else {
            args <- c("-oq", shQuote(zipfile))
            if (length(files)) 
                args <- c(args, shQuote(files))
            if (exdir != ".") 
                args <- c(args, "-d", shQuote(exdir))
            system2(unzip, args, stdout = NULL, stderr = NULL, 
                invisible = TRUE)
            invisible(NULL)
        }
    }
}
```

In this, I modified lines: 1 (arguments), 6 (`utils:::`), 21-25 (`dashl`), 45 and added 46-47 (column choosing). The rest is from the original R `unzip` function.

By default, `unzip2` will behave exactly as `unzip`, meaning it will not give you what you want. In order to get your desired results, you need to (a) tell it where you external `unzip.exe` is located, and (b) tell it you want it to be verbose. (Feel free to modify the above definition to change the defaults.)

Note that on Windows, `unzip.exe` is typically not installed by default. It is included in [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), [Git-for-Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), and [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/). You may need a little more effort to ensure `Sys.which("unzip")` finds the executable.

This uses the (default) internal C function, meaning nothing more can come.

```
unzip2("~/bashdotfiles.zip", list = TRUE)
#            Name Length                Date
# 1 .bash_history   8269 2017-02-20 03:31:00
# 2  .bash_logout    220 2016-04-22 22:36:00
# 3       .bashrc   3771 2016-04-22 22:36:00
```

This uses the external executable, and is functionally identical (though notice the dates are different due to internal UTC conversion ... this could be fixed with a little more effort).

```
unzip2("~/bashdotfiles.zip", list = TRUE, unzip = Sys.which("unzip"))
#            Name Length                Date
# 1 .bash_history   8269 2017-02-20 11:31:00
# 2  .bash_logout    220 2016-04-23 05:36:00
# 3       .bashrc   3771 2016-04-23 05:36:00
```

Finally, the augmented listing:

```
unzip2("~/bashdotfiles.zip", list = TRUE, list.verbose = TRUE, unzip = Sys.which("unzip"))
#            Name Length                Date Method Size Cmpr   CRC.32
# 1 .bash_history   8269 2017-02-20 11:31:00 Defl:N 2717  67% 99c8d736
# 2  .bash_logout    220 2016-04-23 05:36:00 Defl:N  158  28% 6ce3189b
# 3       .bashrc   3771 2016-04-23 05:36:00 Defl:N 1740  54% ab254644
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! However, it seems that there is some kind of bug in the code. If one of the files inside zip has spaces in its file name, then the code crashes. For example, I tried to run a code on a zip file which includes inside one file named "a b.pdf". The code returns the following values `502521,  b.PDF , Defl:N,  <NA>,  448514,   11%,  2016-05-18, a`. If the file name has more than 1 spaces then the code crashes.

Comment: Does this happen with `utils::unzip()`?

Comment: That's a bug in `unzip` whenever an external unzip executable is used. This `unzip2` dutifully replicates that behavior :-).

Comment: Yes, it does, as long as I am using non internal unzip.exe. I tried the one in Git folder as well as the one in RbuildTools. Both do exactly the same. Only when I use internal unzip.exe (default argument) it works OK, but in this case I am not getting the compression ratio information with unzip2.

Comment: Any idea how to resolve it? I have hundreds of zip files with hundreds of internal files in each and I need to analyze compression ratios of those files (grouped by the file type)

Comment: You can try replacing `read.table` with `readr::read_table`. You might also want to define `col_names` and `col_types`, otherwise you'll get the a warning message every time.